# Insert array of value in particular attribute through core data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, nsarray

I have the json value like this ,

```
    {
    "product_color" = Black;
            "product_description" = "The new Macbook air is ultraslim";
            "product_id" = 1;
            "product_large_image_url" = "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/3_webp_ll.png";
            "product_name" = "MacBook Air";
            "product_price" = "$2500";
            "product_size" = Small;
            "product_stocks" = 50;
            "product_thumb_image_url" =         (
                "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2_webp_ll.png",
                 ......
                 ......
            );
```

}

and I want to insert the `product_thumb_image_url` array in a single attribute through        core data,

what i have tried is:

```
    +(void)insertingProduct:  (int16_t) cId :(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
            DataModel *dModel = [self dataModel];
           Products *productDetails=[dModel createEntity:products];
           productDetails.product_id=[[dictionary valueForKey:productid] integerValue];
           productDetails.product_large_image_url = [dictionary valueForKey:productlargeImage];
            productDetails.product_name=[dictionary valueForKey:productname];
          productDetails.product_price=[[dictionary valueForKey:productPrice] integerValue];
          productDetails.product_sizes=[dictionary valueForKey:productsizes];
          productDetails.product_stocks=[[dictionary valueForKey:productstocks] integerValue];
          productDetails.product_colors=[dictionary valueForKey:productcolors];
          productDetails.product_description=[dictionary valueForKey:productdescription];
         productDetails.product_thumb_image_url=[dictionary valueForKey:productThumbImage];

    [dModel save];
}
```

but it shows that you can't insert an `NSArray` into an `NSString`, i am struggling to fix this ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, `product_thumb_image_url` is a `String` attribute in Core Data and `[dictionary valueForKey:productThumbImage]` returns an `NSArray` of URL strings from your incoming JSON.

So `productDetails.product_thumb_image_url=[dictionary valueForKey:productThumbImage];` tries to store an array as a string, which obviously ins't possible.

You either need to store an `Array` in Core Data, which is done by making the attribute transformable, or you need to store only one image URL, which would be done by taking only the first item from the array (you should check that the array contains some items):

```
[[dictionary valueForKey:productThumbImage] firstObject]
```

Comment: Thank you so much i have changed the property to transformable so that i can access it

Comment: ya wain definitely How could i contact you in personal for any doubts

Comment: You can't ;-) Just open new questions if you have them and someone will help if they can